# Resetting WP_HOME?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to enable my wordpress to the local network, and since XAMPP's listen, my firewall enabling ports, and wordpress changing address through the dashboard didn't work, I tried a couple of things people kept saying it worked wonders.

I went to wp-config.php and set the constants of WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME, I knew the dashboard would be ignored due to hardcoding, but I wasn't expecting at all that even after removing the two lines of code from the file, they would still be valid.

So yeah, now my wordpress is unable to redirect to homepage and so far I didn't find a way to reset the hardcoding I did. Is there a solution to this?

Edit:

I found it really weird that regardless of what IP was on WP_SITEURL or WP_HOME, the dashboard would let me set up the address there and save it (either it being localhost or not). I decided to try some incorrect IPs to see if anything would happen and the website crashed (as expected), reusing the correct IP or imputing "localhost" on wp-config brought the site back on **without letting me change the dashboard (normal behaviour for once, I guess)**.

**However** removing the lines of code makes the website crash.

And the home page is never redirected like it was before the code either way. And yes, updating which page should be homedoesn't work =/

Comment: Did you install a fresh copy of wordpress or you are trying to install from a backup ?

Comment: It was a fresh copy now with plugins that at worst modify taxonomy and add new post-types. I never used anything on wp_config before so after the ctrl+zs and saving it is pretty much like it came from.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the settings persisted is because WordPress saved them to the database. Using `define ('WP_HOME', 'localhost')` in wp-config.php is just a shortcut for updating an option in the database.

To change it back, you'll need to repeat the same process, but with the original values.

That is, add the following to your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME', '[original value]');
define('WP_SITEURL', '[original value]');
```

As for your original issue, it might be that you don't have Apache configured correctly, or that file permissions are not appropriately set. If WordPress isn't able to create or modify `.htaccess` you can run into these kinds of issues.

Source https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: is "[original value]" supposed to be replaced by the original or is it like a short code? Because regardless of using localhost or my actual IP, wordpress on the dashboard would actually try its the ip+url, say, http://192.168.0.18/wordpress, when if I looked down on the browser it would try one of the wrong IPs

Comment: I meant for you to put the original value, it's not a short code

Comment: I tried several times with local host and the actual IP and it didn't work. Had to change straight for the database. Still, thank you for the attention and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so, to sum up: I got tired of **anything using "define" on wp-config not working** (even exactly the same code), and went to phpMyAdmin and **found out that even though the address would change on the dashboard, the database would still hold a previous value.**

**The solution was to just change the value directly on the database's wp_options.** Still, it didn't change until I cleaned my cache completely, nice to know you have my back, Firefox. **The downside is that just like hardcoding in php, it doesn't let you change on the dashboard.** But honestly, it is redirecting again as it should so I don't care.

Regardless, thank you all for the help and patience, and if you're here because you also had this problem, good luck.

Comment: FYI: using `define(WP_HOME, '...')` in wp-config.php will override the value that is in the database (it's a filter `_config_wp_home` on `option_home`). There could be other filters (e.g. `pre_option_home`) applied that return different values, but that's uncommon. Always debug these things with dev tools open and "Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)" option checked, as redirects will be cached as well.

Comment: I'm aware of what WP_HOMe does, which is why this problem was so insanely odd to me that it didn't overwrite. I'm pretty sure there were no filters if they don't come as default, but I will keep an eye on the HTTP Cache, thanks for the tip =)

Comment: Check out wp-cli, it's much easier to use than willing sql imo

Answer (score -1):

define('WP_HOME', '[original value]');
define('WP_SITEURL', '[original value]');

define('RELOCATE',true);

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.